# Unity3d Android How to open native file manager

Tags: android, file, unity-game-engine, file-browser

i'm trying to save a custom file on my android device with Unity3d but i'm looking for a way that opens the native file browser so that the user can decide where to save the file.
How can i do that?
the file is a json with a custom extention.

Answer (score 1):

Unity does not expose an API to do this. Instead, you'll need to use a native Android plugin. There are several on the asset store, or you can use one called "UnityNativeFilePicker" on github.